# (Selenium) How i can click several buttons with same class, but with dynamic href only?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click all these buttons and selenium need to identify how many these buttons on the page.

```xml
<a style="margin-left: 10px;" href="/home/edit?Pproduct=d08983fca254&amp; source=my-products” class="rlg-btn-secondary xh-
highlight” >Edit</a>

<a style="margin-left: 10px;" href="/home/edit?product=3191d95e8233&amp; source=my-products” class="rlg-btn-secondary” >Edit</a>
```

Comment: In webdriver we have concept of getElements it it will give all elements as per provided locator. Figure it out locator which gives all buttons in ur case and then use those web elements

Comment: By using find_elements you can get all the elements, example: ```driver.find_elements_by_link_text("sometext")``` But if you want some specific element then you can use indexing like example ```"//a[text()='Edit'][1]"```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all of your links have text **Edit** (As shown in given snippet). You can first get list of all elements with same property and then perform what ever action you want by navigating them one by one.

```
# To get list of all links with text Edit
buttonsList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='Edit']")
# Traverse to each element in list
for bth in buttonsList:
    btn.click()  # or perform action, whatever you want here.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use findelements by list class in selenium.

List<WebElement> editbuttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*a[contains(text(),"Edit")]));

// To get number of edit buttons

Int count=editbuttons.size();
```

// if you want 1 st button
editbuttons.get(0).click();

//all edit buttons are storing as list in selenium